# Testing static routes in compojure

Tags: testing, clojure, compojure

I am trying to write a test for the compojure static content route.
I am testing the routes by examining the ring response directly.

A minimal working example is as follows:

```
;; src/testing-webapps.core.clj
(ns testing-webapps.core
  (:use [compojure.core]
        [compojure.route   :as route]))

(defroutes web-app
   (route/resources "/")
   (route/not-found "404"))


;; test/testing-webapps.core_test.clj
(ns testing-webapps.core-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [testing-webapps.core :refer :all]))

(defn request [resource web-app & params]
  (web-app {:request-method :get :uri resource :params (first params)}))

(deftest test-routes
  (is (= 404 (:status (request "/flubber" web-app))))
  (is (= "404" (:body (request "/flubber" web-app))))
  (is (= 200 (:status (request "/test.txt" web-app)))))
```

Testing the 404 route works fine but calling `(request "/test.txt" web-app)` leads to an unexpected `NullPointerException` in `ring.middleware.file-info/not-modified-since?`.

Here is the top part of the stacktrace:

```
ERROR in (test-routes) (file_info.clj:27)
Uncaught exception, not in assertion.
expected: nil
  actual: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at ring.middleware.file_info$not_modified_since_QMARK_.invoke (file_info.clj:27)
    ring.middleware.file_info$file_info_response.doInvoke (file_info.clj:44)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:442)
    ring.middleware.file_info$wrap_file_info$fn__917.invoke (file_info.clj:64)
    [...]
```

The static route works fine in the browser but not when called through my `request` function.

Is there an easier way to test a static route in compojure and why do I get a NullPointerException when calling the static route with my own request map?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the source for [`not-modified-since?`](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/master/ring-core/src/ring/middleware/file_info.clj#L27), I think the issue is you have no headers in your request map, so it throws a NPE on this expr: `(headers "if-modified-since")`.  Try changing your `request` method like so:

```
(defn request [resource web-app & params]
  (web-app {:request-method :get 
            :headers {"content-type" "text/plain"} ; added a header
            :uri resource 
            :params (first params)}))
```

You might also consider using [`ring-mock`](https://github.com/weavejester/ring-mock) to create requests for testing.  It insulates you a little bit from stuff like this.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to ring-mock. It looks very much like a useful tool.